# Javascripts Timing Events, Countdown and Display

Tags: javascript

I'm new on learning javascript. I'm working on my school project and I faced some problems. I want to create a countdown timer and also display it out indicating "3,2,1...". Creating this for a photo capturing system by using HTML5 and JS.

When user click on the button that said CAPTURE, there will be a line of word written down "Photo will be captured in (3,2,1)". Then call the function below.

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
```

I know can done by using

```
setTimeout(function(){context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480)},3000);
```

but I don't know how to link it with the button that written "CAPTURE", and display the indicator by saying 3, 2, and then 1.

sorry for the poor english that I wrote.

Comment: You can use setTimeout() three times in loop

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
var currectValue = 0;
var timer = -1;
function onTimer(){
    if(currentValue == 0){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        return;
    }

    currentValue -= 1;

    //Your code
}

function startCountdown(seedValue){
    currentValue = seedValue;
    if(-1 != timer){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = -1;
    }

    timer = setInterval(onTimer, 1000);
}

startCountdown(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example,

```
function timer(object){
 if(object==0)
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
 else{
  object = object -1;
  setTimeout("timer('"+object+"')",1000);
 }

}
```

Externally call like onclick="timer(3)"